# How do I delay a method for turn-based game in Java Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, delay

In a simple card game (human vs. CPU) the logic works, but I want to delay the computer's turn.

I have tried using `Thread.sleep(int milliseconds)` which works, but it messes up the order images are displayed. I'm not using a game loop, I am just dynamically updating ImageViews whenever cards are changed. The problem with Thread.sleep is all the images only update *after* Thread.sleep, there is no displaying only the human card before Thread.sleep. The human's card and computer's card display after Thread.sleep.

I've used Thread.sleep like so:

```
playPlayerCard(player); // Human first
displayPile(); // Display card pile (ImageView's)

player = nextPlayer(player); // Get's next player in Player mPlayers List<Player>

// Wait for computer to 'Think'
Thread.sleep(500);

playPlayerCard(player); //Computer's turn
displayPile(); // Display card pile (ImageView's)
```

Am I using Thread.sleep() wrong? Is there a better/correct way? I've searched online and tried using `new Thread()`, using `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long milliseconds)` and also `CountDownTimer` but none work since my variables: `playPlayerCard(player);` aren't final variables.

I've always had problems delaying actions and the images appearing at the correct times. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you could make your variables global - define them in the class body outside of all methods. Then you will be able to use handler.

Comment: @jakar, that worked, thank you. I'm using Handler and Runnable and I changed all the variables I need (just one, so not bad) to a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from @Jakar and changed my variables to class-scope in order to use the Handler and Runnable correctly. This worked, the delay works correctly using

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         playPlayerCard();
    }
};

mHandler.postDelayed(r, 500);
```

To clarify the solution, I had to take out the arguments from `playPlayerCard(Player player)` and use a class-scope `Player mPlayer;` variable in `playPlayerCard()` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you just implement the Computer Playing logic in a AsyncTask and fire it when the human turn is done ?

I think it would make much more sense, that way, as soon as the computer is done "playing" you can determine the actions to take in the `onPostExecute()` method, in your case I think that would be dealing cards.

It would also be really simple to block user inputs while the computer is playing, either with a progress dialog (which isn't all that pleasent for a game I understand) or simply by disabling buttons :)

Here's the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know about AsyncTask. I'll take a look and try it out, looks like a more efficient way of doing turn-based style. I'll see if I can do a quick-fix first, and then try it this way later.

Comment: I'm currently going to use Handler and Runnable, but thanks for the info, down the road I may use AsyncTask.